# Is my job offer sure?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, india

The HR of a company contacted me and told me that they are very much interested in hiring me and also want me to join as soon as possible. But the salary negotiation didn't go well. Neither they were able to convince me, nor I was able to convince them. But still after 2 days they were asking for proof of my current compensation. Does that mean the job offer is sure?

Comment: I'm sure others share the same feelings as me. I never show my current compensation. It is none of their business.

Comment: "*Does that mean the job offer is sure?*" - I would guess that *no*. They just want that info to better negotiate the salary.

Comment: By the way. I had already told them that I will forgo this offer if compensation is less than a particular number when salary negotiation was happening

Comment: Maybe there was a miscommunication somewhere and someone thinks you accepted the lower offer. Maybe they plan on offering you the salary you asked for. We don't know what they're thinking, but [a job offer is only certain after you sign the contract (or later)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/exactly-when-in-the-hiring-process-of-a-new-job-should-i-give-a-two-week-notice) and I don't really see the harm in complying with their request, assuming you actually told them what your current compensation is, or it's close to what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, I am pretty sure that there was no misconception here. And I had clearly told them about the expected compensation of mine which is around 80-100%  more than my current compensation and they know this clearly.

Comment: @user5001880 What is your location? In the state of California in the US, asking for current compensation is illegal.

Comment: I am from India

Comment: Why are you asking us? Ask someone at the company. It sounds like either they're still trying to make up their minds or their internal communication is lacking.

Comment: @user5001880 Let's assume for a moment your offer is "sure". If they offer you less than your minimum expected compensation, are you willing to reconsider accepting the offer? I have a fair idea what might be going on behind the scenes here, your clarification to this question will help me post an answer for you.

Comment: @user5001880 Did you, at any point during the application process, tell them what your current salary was? Are they aware that you are asking for a 80% to 100% hike over your current salary?

Comment: @MaskedMan yes they know what my current compensation is and they are also aware that I am asking for 80-100% salary hike

Comment: @Maskedman I communicated to them while salary negotiation which didn't go well that I am not going to accept the offer if the compensation offered is less than my minimum expectation

Comment: Do you know what the average salary for the position is, and how it compares to their offer/your expectations?

Comment: I don´t know if that is different in India, but here in Europe I would not provide any information about previous pay. What I demand for a certain task in the future has nothing to do with what I got under different circumstances in the past. The only thing that matters is, if the future employer is prepared to meet my demands - *or else they can just go find somebody else!* To me the asking for proof of previous compensation is a red flag that there will be trouble with pay!

Answer (score 4):

> Is my job offer sure?

No, nothing is concrete yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the offer is "sure", in the sense that they surely want you, at their offer. That is, if you say "yes, I accept your offer", then they will produce a contract.

As soon as you start trying to negotiate upwards, it is no longer 100% sure. That doesn't mean, though, that they will reject you out of hand for merely negotiating , but don't take too long about it, or they might get tired of you.

Answer (score 0):

A job offer is never sure until the end of your probation period.

Signed contract can be withdrawn before start with no or small penalties, and this is normally mentioned in them.

Employment can be terminated during the probation period, and this is also stated in the contract.

In your case you didn't even sign a contract, just heard an oral statement.

You didn't catch the bear yet, so don't sell its skin.